# Linear map applied three times

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to study a linear map that takes a vector of $\mathbb{C}^3$ and change it into another vector in $\mathbb{C}^3$. I then have to cube this linear map. I wonder if cubing a linear application means that each term has to be cubed, or something else?

Comment: It means apply the linear map 3 times: $T^3(x) = T(T(T(x)))$.

Comment: The task was put to you in a moderately imprecise way. More precise, I think, would have been to ask you to describe or express the three-fold iteration of the map.

Answer (score 1):

A linear map in finite dimensions may always be represented by a matrix. So, if you want to take a point $z = (z_1,z_2,z_3) \in \mathbb{C}^3$ to a point $w = (w_1,w_2,w_3)\in\mathbb{C}^3$ you can write this as $Az = w$ for some matrix $A$. Applying the map twice would be $A w = A(Az) = A^2 z$. Hence applying it thrice would be $A^3 z$.